# Spanning $\Bbb{R}^2$ Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Does anyone have an idea about how to prove this:

> Let $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb R^2$. Prove: $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\} = \mathbb R^2$ if and only if $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent.

I thought about showing that $v_1, v_2$ are the unit vectors of $\mathbb R^2$, but then someone told me that this assumption can be wrong.

Comment: The answer in the above post is "1. If $V$ is finite dimensional with $\dim(V)=n$, then a set of $n$ vectors of $V$ spans $V$ if and only if they are linearly independent (this may be what you were aiming for or trying to recall). The proof is in every book on linear algebra.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $2$ vectors do not span, say, $\Bbb R^3$ even if they are linearly independent. But in your case $n=2$ for both, so it is a standard result for every lecture in linear algebra. And no need to use "unit" vectors.

Comment: Well, there are two cases: either $v_1,v_2$ is linearly dependent, or they're independent. What is the dimension of ${\rm span}(v_1,v_2)$ in each of this case?

Comment: This is something I haven't learned yet.
Maybe that's what my instructor meant to show by this question. But again, I don't know how to prove it ..

Comment: You have the germ of a good idea.  There are two directions to prove ("if and only if"), so let's pick the forward implication to discuss.  Assume that  $v_1,v_2$ *span* all of $\mathbb R^2$.  We want to prove that they are then linearly independent.  Suppose for contradiction that the two vectors are *not* linearly independent.  Use the definition, which says two vectors are *linearly dependent* if they satisfy a certain equation.  If you know the definition, you will be able to make some progress on this part of the problem.  If not, you need to drop back and check the definition.

Answer (score 1):

We need to break this problem into two parts.

1. If ${v_1,v_2}$ are linearly dependent then they do not span $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. If $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent then they do span $\mathbb{R}^2$

For the first part ask yourself what does it mean for two vectors to be linearly dependent? How will the span look in this case?

For part two you need to explain why every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$. In other words, you need to explain why for every vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we can solve the equation $v = av_1 +bv_2$. Do you know how to solve an equation like this? They should have taught you how to do this in class. You need to explain why you know your method will work.

Comment: I think that I have missed something here.
When $v_1, v_2$ are linearly dependent it supposed to say something about them (probably the reason why they cann't span $R^2$) but I don't get what is it

Comment: Try watching this video on linear dependence: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/linear-independence/v/linear-algebra-introduction-to-linear-independence

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, if $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ is LI, we conclude $\operatorname{span}\{v_{1},v_{2}\} = \mathbb{R}^{2}$. That is because $\dim\mathbb{R}^{2} = 2$.

On the other hand, if $\operatorname{span}\{v_{1},v_{2}\} = \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $\mathcal{B} = \{v_{1},v_{2}\}$ is LI. Otherwise we could conclude that $v_{1} = \alpha v_{2}$, that is to say, $\operatorname{span}\{v_{1},v_{2}\} = \operatorname{span}\{v_{2}\} = \mathbb{R}^{2}$, which contradicts the fact that $\dim\mathbb{R}^{2} = 2$.